# Does APs require re-association after channel switch announcemnt?

Tags: wifi

If an AP encountered RADAR and requires to change channel. And the new channel that AP moved will be announced in channel switch announcement action frame to all clients which are connected to that AP. In this case, does all clients (Stations) required to re associate with the AP with the new channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- An AP shall inform associated STAs that the AP is moving to a new channel and **maintain the association by advertising the switch using Channel Switch Announcement elements in Beacon frames, Probe Response frames, and Channel Switch Announcement frames** until the intended channel switch time.

--The AP may force STAs in the BSS to stop transmissions until the channel switch takes place by setting the Channel Switch Mode field in the Channel Switch Announcement element to 1.

--The channel switch should be scheduled so that all STAs in the BSS, including STAs in power save mode, have the opportunity to receive at least one Channel Switch Announcement element before the switch.

--The AP may send the Channel Switch Announcement frame in a BSS without performing a backoff, after determining the WM is idle for one PIFS period.
A STA that receives a Channel Switch Announcement element may choose not to perform the specified switch, but to take alternative action. For example, it may choose to move to a different BSS.

--A STA in a BSS that is not the AP shall not transmit the Channel Switch Announcement element